# 403 Forbidden when accessing image

Tags: apache, error-handling, permissions, errordocument, httpforbiddenhandler

I am trying to access this file via URL on my server and it gives me the 403 forbidden error. I've checked the permissions of the directory containing the file and the file itself and changed them both to 755. Still, I am unable to change it. I don't know what could be wrong with it. I'm simply editing a site someone else originally created, so I imagine its some setting they've created but I don't even know where to begin to look. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You need all the directories in the image path to have the right permissions, not just the one directly containing the file. Worth checking this.

Comment: @sfThomas Yes the file permissions are 755 all the way down to the root folder

Comment: You'll need to post your apache config & the file's path.

Comment: @sfThomas I'm using an online File Manager and cant set commands to find my Apache config file. I didnt create the site so I'm not sure how they set it up. But the image's path is public_html/airkrete/uploads/air-krete-logo.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the web developer before me enabled Hotlink Protection and blocked '.pngs' from being directly accessed. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thanks, This solved my problem. I was trying with the .htaccess